# json.stringify return null array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

I have an object which I created like the following,

```
var test=[];
test.car=1
test.bike=2
test.cycle=3
```

> Result: [car: 1, bike: 2, cycle: 3]

and i have a controller which is expecting

```
public ActionResult insertTransport(transportModal test)
```

when i write `data:JSON.stringify(test)`
the value from `data:JSON.stringify(test)` is coming like `[]` what i need to do to stringify the object test?

Comment: No, the result is `[]`

Comment: Array's don't work like that ... try `test = {}` ... JSON stringifying an Array iterates through it - so ... looks for test[0], test[1], test[2] to test[test.length - 1] ... since test.length is zero, the result is `[]`

Comment: Use a regular object, not an array. Arrays are special cased.